# Show/Hide <tr> based on dropdown select - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following `array` of `objects` in my `controller`:

```
$scope.reportsValuesOptions = [  
   {  
      "value":"Cash Position Report",
      "option":"Cash Position Report"
   },
   {  
      "value":"Detail Report",
      "option":"Detail Report"
   },
   {  
      "value":"Reconciliation Report",
      "option":"Reconciliation Report"
   },
   {  
      "value":"Summary Report",
      "option":"Summary Report"
   },
   {  
      "value":"Sweep Report",
      "option":"Sweep Report"
   },
   {  
      "value":"FCCS/FBPS Detail Report",
      "option":"FCCS/FBPS Detail Report"
   },
   {  
      "value":"CustomReport",
      "option":"Custom Report Name"
   }
];
```

Here is my `dropdown` which gets populated based on the above `array`:

```
<select name="rname" id="rname" ng-model="rname" ng-options="report.option for report in reportsValuesOptions track by report.value">
    <option value="">---Select---</option>
</select>
```

Here is the row which I want to show based on above dropdown value

```
<tr ng-if="rname === CustomReport">
    <td class="label-cell">* Custom account Number(s) :</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="custaccountNumber" name="custaccountNumber" ng-model="custaccountNumber" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to show a `<tr>` only if my dropdown value changes to `'CustomReport'`

**[FULL EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/jn4vp1qa/)**

When I run the html the `<tr>` gets displayed, and as soon as I select ANY option, it hides. I want the `<tr>` to be hidden BY DEFAULT and show ONLY WHEN I select `'CustomReport'` value option from the dropdown. It should hide on selecting any other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to your `ngModel` actually be an `object`, you have to use single quotes in your comparison, as below:

```
<tr ng-if="rname.value === 'CustomReport'">
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/jn4vp1qa/1/)</kbd>